# How to find the line number of an error in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I am running the following command:

> make -f makefile.gcc

And the output is:

> make: -c: Command not found

How can I find out which line is causing the error? The makefile is hundreds of lines long and there's no way of figuring it out otherwise.

I tried the `-d` switch, but that didn't print any useful information.

Comment: Which system are you running on? There are some tricks there that might help knowing that. What does the dry run say? Maybe you get more info from that. (make -n -f makefile.gcc)

Comment: @Knubo: I'm on Ubuntu compiling with Mingw-w64. (The output of the dry run is not useful because some of the targets depend on the commands being run.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that the makefile contain paths with '\' in them and since I'm running on Linux, that's going to be a problem.

I'm still [working on a solution for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060744/simple-way-of-converting-slashes-in-a-makefile).

Comment: @Knubo - you figured it out :)

Comment: Are there only a makefile or is there a configure script with the project as well? Maybe you can recreate the makefile on the unix platform. As for paths, paths on a windows platform would not make much sense on a linux platform, so just doing a query replace will probably not get you where you want to.

Comment: @Knubo: Here's the problem... the library I'm compiling is cross-platform and *does* come with a `configure` script for Linux/Unix - however, I'm trying to use Mingw64 to compile the library for Win64. The problem is that the library's makefile for Win64 uses paths with '\' in them. I actually can compile it with Mingw64 **on Windows**, but trying to compile it with Mingw64 on Linux isn't working.

Comment: Most paths referenced like that often comes with a configure switch. Try locate one of the culprits and see if the configure script has a way of providing it. If so, maybe you can run the configure script with some extra settings and get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you locate what goes wrong if you do run strace on the make command. Then you can search the makefile for that afterwards.

Here's a link to a post about strace:
http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2006/05/strace-very-powerful-troubleshooting.html