# Simple way of converting slashes in a Makefile?

Tags: replace, makefile, path-separator

I need to convert all paths with '\' in them to '/'. The makefile is quite long and doing this manually is impossible.

Is there some way to quickly convert them? Keep in mind that a global replace is not possible because '\' is also used to denote that a command is continued on the following line.

Comment: Can you use unix command ? `sed -i 's/\\/\//g' yourfile`

Comment: I sooo though "regex" when reading this. They are often misused, but when they are appropriate, you gotta love them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you could do this with a `sed` command:

```
sed -e 's/\\\(.\)/\/\1/g'
```

This converts any backslash followed by some other character (which doesn't include newline) into a forward slash followed by that same character.

This command line has a bit of a "leaning toothpick" problem, sorry about that.

Comment: You don't have to use `/` as your command separator. This would look a bit nicer as `sed -e 's:\\\(.\):/\1:g`.

Comment: @Jack Kelly: That's true, but `sed` still requires that you quote the parentheses (otherwise it tries to match them literally).

Comment: Indeed, but it does make it a little less of a "leaning toothpick" command. I messed up when I was typing the comment, and now cannot edit it. Here it is again: `sed 's:\\\(.\):/\1:g'`

Answer (score 0):

I think that Gregs solution was nearly correct, but I would do

```
sed -e 's/\\\(.\)/\/\1/g'
```

to make sure that not only the first slash gets replaced. Sorry for not doing this as a comment, but I don't have the privilege yet.